# md-datepicker is not showing current month / year when opens

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material in some screens, it works fine, however I'm having some issues when using [md-datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) component. At the moment of this post, the current date is 2016-12-19, so, I believe when a user clicks on date-picker it should show the current month, so user can select a near day.
However what I'm getting is a date far from current date, for example 2017 february, as you can see below.

[image: date-picker]

I have no idea of what is going on, my code uses the correctly declaration:

```
<div ng-if="opcoes.prazo=='D'">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="promocao.dataInicio" md-placeholder="Início" md-open-on-focus md-min-date="opcoes.hoje" required></md-datepicker>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="promocao.dataTermino" md-placeholder="Fim" md-open-on-focus md-min-date="promocao.dataInicio" required></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

**DECLARATION OF opcoes AND promocao OBJECTS**

```
$scope.opcoes = {dias: 'E', horario: 'X', prazo: 'D', hoje: new Date()};
$scope.promocao = {diasArray: [], dataInicio: null, dataTermino: null};
```

**IT IS HAPPENING ONLY IN CHROME**

I've tested this same code on Firefox and it is running correctly.
The [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) has the same problem, only in Chrome. Click on ***"View source"*** button and then open any datepicker, it happens only when the source code is shown.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Please paste promocao and opcoes object along with data, So it would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material Datepicker opening position is wrong in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324991/angular-material-datepicker-opening-position-is-wrong-in-chrome)